# Numbered Variables Into a Function

Tags: php, foreach

I don't know if there's another way to do this, but I have a list of variables that were passed through another script and I need to validate the data.

```
$itempuname0 = $_POST['itempuname0'];
$itempuname1 = $_POST['itempuname1'];
$itempuname2 = $_POST['itempuname2'];
$itempuname3 = $_POST['itempuname3'];
$itempuemail0 = $_POST['itempuemail0'];
$itempuemail1 = $_POST['itempuemail1'];
$itempuemail2 = $_POST['itempuemail2'];
$itempuemail3 = $_POST['itempuemail3'];
```

Further down in the script, I'm pulling information from a session. Each item in the session lists in the same order these variables are passed through.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
    $total = 0;
    $cart_items = 0;

    sort($_SESSION["products"]);
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cartitem) {
        $showid = $cartitem["code"];
        $name = $cartitem['name'];
        $original = $cartitem['original'];
        $price = $cartitem['price'];
        $quantity = $cartitem["qty"];
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that I can define $itempuname and $itempuemail without the numbers in that foreach function? Thank you!

Comment: `sort($_SESSION["products"]);` seems redundant; you only need to do this when the array gets updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "define without the numbers"? There are four of each, so isn't it important to use the correct one?

Comment: how do the variables on top and the session variable relate?

Comment: Jack: Yes, I do want to use the correct one, so the first time it loops it uses 0, then 1, etc. I just want the variable defined that way for when the data is inserted. The sequence of the numbers and where it arrives in the foreach() will correlate.

Comment: Why not use an array?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aredan, I'm not sure if i understand your question. I assume you want to assign post variables in a loop based on the numbers in the variable. You can use '[variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)' of PHP. Check below code,

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    $namevar   = 'itempuname'.$i;
    $emailvar  = 'itempuemail'.$i;
    $$namevar  = $_POST[$namevar];
    $$emailvar = $_POST[$emailvar];
}
```